# Xbox 360 controller right motor makes loud noise

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I got a brand new xbox 360 controller yesterday. The buttons are good, soft and responsive but I think I have a problem with the right motor. It mostly make sound while not vibrates at all !!!

**Long story**: I play Assassin Creed Brotherhood for a while and feel the vibration's weak. So I follow this [**thread**](http://www.getdare.com/bbs/archive/index.php/t-146897.html) to try test the vibration . I download both `x360ce_lib32_r848_VS2010.zip` and `x360ce.App-2.1.2.191.zip`, put them in the same folder and run the program. However, it need something and tell me it will download it but take forever to load (internet is OK).

[image: Pic1: it need something]

Pic 1: the program need something.

[image: Pic 2: If I skip it, there's a warning]

Pic 2: If I skip it, there's a warning

Despite that, the program still recognizes correctly all the inputs. Then I try to test the vibration, the left is ok but the right one just make a loud noise while the vibration is weaker. I tell the support guy and he say the reason is those 2 motors are different. I still can return it if I want.

**Short story:**
It's make a loud noise when it vibrates, the sound is totally different than the left motor.

**My question is**: is my controller is bad? Should I return it or use another tool to test the controller again?

Comment: if its brand new it might have warranty/support. Contact microsoft directly.

Comment: What model controller is it specifically?  Can you link to a store page or anything?  I'm wondering what generation of Xbox 360 controller it is, if it's a Microsoft model or 3rd party, and wired vs wireless might matter as well.

Comment: I'm currently working with support guy to determine the problem of the controller. I will give you feedback later. If you have a Xbox 360 controller, please use x360ce to test the vibration of both motors and post it here :)

Comment: By the way, I found this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepad.setvibration.aspx) about the different of the two motors: one with high frequency and the other is low. But mine sound like it's broken :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a "answer", but I had a similar problem with a wired controller that my brother traded me. I don't mod but I like to "tweak" stuff like controllers just cause. I opened it up and the leads to the motor I was having the issues with were shot. I grabbed 2 motors from RadioShack, replaced the ones in the controller and everything was fine after that. I've even taken motors from old tape players and used them. But your controller is new so you may not be to fond of cracking it open. But if it can't be returned and there's no warranty, it's worth a shot, in my opinion. It's real easy to do, just make sure you're not using different size motors. Hope this helped in some way..

Answer (score 1):

An Xbox 360 gamepad should not make loud sounds during rumble, you should return or exchange it.